# zlib gunzip decompresses different buffer sizes each run on the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, gunzip

I'm downloading a daily export gzip file from The Movie Database and decompressing it with zlib. When the `end` event is hit, I log the length of the string of data I decompressed. The length is different every time.

It appears that the data isn't fully getting decompressed. I noticed this when I started parsing the JSON that the file actually contains. It would get half-way through converting each line of JSON (each line represents a stand-alone json object) and blow up because the json was malformed.

```
var http = require('http');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var downloadUrl = "http://files.tmdb.org/p/exports/movie_ids_03_01_2018.json.gz";
http.get(downloadUrl, function(response) {
    var fileContents = "";
    var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

    gunzip.on('data', function(data) {
        fileContents += data.toString();
    });

    gunzip.on('end', function() {
        console.log(fileContents.length);
    });

    response.pipe(gunzip);
});
```

Am I using the gunzip events incorrectly?

I have a [reproducible example](https://repl.it/@scionwest/nodejs-zlib-issue) you can execute to see it running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing my usage of `http` with `request`. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong with `http.get` but piping the `gunzip` into the `request` return value solved my problem.

```
var request = require('request');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var fs = require('fs');

var downloadUrl = "http://files.tmdb.org/p/exports/movie_ids_03_01_2018.json.gz";
var response = request(downloadUrl);
var fileContents = "";
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

gunzip.on('data', function(data) {
    fileContents += data.toString();
});

gunzip.on('end', function() {
    var json = fileContents.split('\n').filter(function(value, index) {
        if (value == "") {
            console.log(index + " is empty and skipped.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
});

response.pipe(gunzip);
```

I tried to use `request.get(options, function(error, response, body){});` but could not pipe `gunzip` into the response or body. I'm new to streams and need to research more to figure out what was wrong. In the mean time, the solution above works without a problem.

Since this runs once a day, as an Azure Function, running it synchronously like this isn't a big deal. I'm not blocking any further work.